# recargar parte de una pagina con load jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

lo que quiero es que al hacer click sobre el boton  identificado como registro cargue el div registro-usuario  de la pagina registro en el div de la pagina principal, el div se identifica como datos-usuario. Se que con ajax se puede pero por lo que entiendo esta mas orientado a servidores y mi situación es que ambas paginas están en la misma carpeta en mi pc.

el index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="css/font-awesome.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body><!800 y 320 para responsivo>
    <header>
        <p class="titulo">Liquid Health</p>
    </header>
    <nav id="menu-productos"></nav>
    <main>
        <div class="contenedor">
            <div id="datos-usuario">
                <p class="titulo-usuario">Registro/Inicio de sesión</p>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="Usuario" placeholder="Usuario/Email">
                <input type="password" id="password" name="Contraseña" placeholder="Contraseña">
                <input type="submit" id="login" name="Login" placeholder="Login" value="Ingresar">
                <input type="button" id="registro" name="registro" value="Registrarse">
                
            </div>
            <section  class="slide-productos">
                <p class="productos">Productos</p>
                <div class="contenedor-productos"></div>
            </section >
            <section class="slide-informativo">
                <p class="informativos"> Informativos</p>
                <section  class="contenedor-informativo"></section>
            </section >
        </div>
    </main>
    <footer class="redes">
    </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

este es el index de mi pagina llamada registro.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="css/font-awesome.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
   <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="registro-usuario">
        <p class="titulo-usuario">Registro</p>
        <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" required>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Usuario/Email" required>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="contraseña" placeholder="Contraseña" required>
        
        <input type="submit" id="registro-final" name="registro-final" value="Registro">
       
    </div >
</body>
</html>
```

el script con el que intento actualizar parcialmente la pagina principal

```
$(Document).ready(function(){
    $("#registro").click(function() {
        $("#datos-usuario").load('registro.html');
       });
})
```

Comment: Puedes usar un modal para mostrar el formulario de registro o tenerlo en la pagina principal en un div oculto por defecto, ambas opciones sólo las muestras al hacer click en el botón y las ocultas al enviar los datos del formulario.

Comment: No es que AJAX esté orientado a servidores, sino que, por razones de seguridad, los navegadores bloquean el acceso a rutas en disco duro. Además, si vas a registrar usuarios, definitivamente necesitas un servidor Web y tienes opciones para instalar en tu equipo, como [Wampserver](https://www.wampserver.com/en/) o [Xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/es/index.html)

Comment: aun no nos enseñan como usar base de datos, por eso quiero hacerlo solo con javaScript o jquery. Revise como hacer la pagina ocultando y mostrando elementos pero pasa que al actualizar carga la vista principal y no donde estaba antes de actualizar la pagina